# help on writing "the colist Monad" (Exercise from an Idioms intro paper)

Tags: haskell, monads, idioms

I'm reading Conor McBride and Ross Paterson's "Functional Pearl / Idioms: applicative programming with effects:" (The <strike>new</strike> version, with "idioms" in the title). I'm having a little difficulty with Exercise 4, which is explained below. Any hints would be much appreciated (especially: should I start writing `fmap` and `join` or `return` and `>>=`?).

#### Problem Statement

You want to create an `instance Monad []` where

```
return x = repeat x
```

and `ap = zapp`.

#### Standard library functions

As on p. 2 of the paper, `ap` applies a monadic function-value to a monadic value.

```
ap :: Monad m => m (s -> t) -> m s -> m t
ap mf ms = do
    f <- mf
    s <- ms
    return (f s)
```

I expanded this in canonical notation to,

```
ap mf ms = mf >>= (\f -> (ms >>= \s -> return (f s)))
```

The list-specific function `zapp` ("zippy application") applies a function from one list to a corresponding value in another, namely,

```
zapp (f:fs) (s:ss) = f s : zapp fs ss
```

#### My difficulties

Note that in the expanded form, `mf :: m (a -> b)` is a list of functions `[(a -> b)]` in our case. So, in the first application of `>>=`, we have

```
(f:fs) >>= mu
```

where `mu = (\f -> (ms >>= \s -> return (f s)))`. Now, we can call `fs >>= mu` as a subroutine, but this doesn't know to remove the first element of `ms`. (recall that we want the resulting list to be [f1 s1, f2 s2, ...]. I tried to hack something but... as predicted, it didn't work... any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

#### Edit 1

I think I got it to work; first I rewrote `ap` with `fmap` and `join` as user "comonad" suggested .

My leap of faith was assuming that `fmap = map`. If anyone can explain how to get there, I'd appreciate it very much. After this, it's clear that `join` works on the list of lists user "comonad" suggested, and should be the diagonal, `\x -> zipWith ((!!) . unL) x [0..]`. My complete code is this:

```
newtype L a = L [a] deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)
unL (L lst) = lst
liftL :: ([a] -> [b]) -> L a -> L b
liftL f = L . f . unL

joinL :: L (L a) -> L a
joinL = liftL $ \x -> zipWith ((!!) . unL) x [0..]

instance Functor L where
    fmap f = liftL (map f)

instance Monad L where
    return x = L $ repeat x
    m >>= g = joinL (fmap g m)
```

hopefully that's right (seems to be the "solution" on p. 18 of the paper) ... thanks for the help, everyone!

Comment: Regarding `fmap`: The `Applicative` laws include the identity `pure f <*> x` = `f <$> x`. You should be able to show `fmap` as being `map` using this. And yes, `join` takes the diagonal of the nested lists--as a follow-up exercise, you could try to show how the diagonal being ill-defined on lists of different lengths breaks the monad laws.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hm. I can't help but think this exercise is a little bit unfair as presented.

> #### *Exercise 4 (the colist Monad)*
>
> Although `repeat` and `zapp` are not the `return` and `ap` of the usual `Monad []` instance,
>   they are none the less the `return` and `ap` of an alternative monad, more suited to
>   the coinductive interpretation of `[]`. What is the `join :: [[x]] → [x]` of this monad?
>
> Comment on the relative efficiency of this monad’s `ap` and our `zapp`.

First, I'm fairly certain that the monad instance in question is **not valid for `[]` in general**. When they say "the coinductive interpretation", I suspect this refers to *infinite lists*. The instance is actually valid for finite lists in certain cases, but not for arbitrary lists in general.

So that's your first, very general, hint--why would a monad instance only be valid for certain lists, particularly infinite ones?

Here's your second hint: `fmap` and `return` are trivial given other definitions earlier in the paper. You already have `return`; `fmap` is only slightly less obvious.

Furthermore, `(>>=)` has an easy implementation in terms of the other functions, as with any `Monad`, which leaves `join` as the crux of the matter. In most cases `(>>=)` is more natural for programming with, but `join` is more conceptually fundamental and in this case, I think, more straightforward to analyze. So I recommend working on that, and forgetting about `(>>=)` for now. Once you have an implementation, you can go back and reconstruct `(>>=)` and check the monad laws to make sure it all works properly.

Finally, suppose for a moment that you have `fmap` available, but nothing else. Given values with type `[a -> b]` and `[a]`, you can combine them to get something of type `[[b]]`. The type of `join` here is `[[a]] -> [a]`. How might you write `join` such that you get the same result here that you would from using `zapp` on the original values? Note that the question about relative efficiency is, as well as a question, a clue about the implementation.

Comment: @camccann: I'm not clear on one point.  If the "coinductive interpretation" refers to infinite lists (I agree this is likely), then wouldn't `repeat` and `zapp` actually form a monad which is unsuited to said coinductive interpretation?  That's the case for `ZipList`, which doesn't have a valid monad instance.  Anyway, I suspect the authors chose this example to make the point that applicative functors are useful in part because they're more general than monads (shame on me, I haven't read the paper yet).

Comment: @John L: Errrh... you're correct that this is equivalent to `ZipList`, but you've missed a couple other things, and I can't really clarify without spoiling the answer to the exercise gatoatigrado is working on. :[

Comment: @camccan: I was afraid of that.  I'll just read the paper and hope that fills in the details.

Comment: @John L: Probably not--I only skimmed it (having read the older version before) but I don't think this particular monad came up outside the exercise, which I quoted in full. That said, it's a good read, so no harm in giving it a go! But if you'd rather a more direct explanation than working through the exercise yourself, feel free to contact me via email.

Comment: @camccann: you're quite right, the paper was useless for this purpose (although otherwise a good read!).  However I did notice that I misread the exercise and was thinking of a regular list monad, not the colist monad.  That cleared it up nicely.

Comment: @John L: Yes, it's certainly very different from the standard `join` for lists! The efficiency comparison is also interesting--it relates to what I might call the "philosophical" difference between `Applicative` and `Monad`, and similar performance differences can exist for other functors--I seem to recall hearing about it regarding parser combinators, for instance.

Answer (score 11):

I just thought I should clarify that the version with exercises and "Idioms" in the title is a rather *earlier* draft of the paper which eventually appeared in JFP. At that time, I mistakenly thought that colists (by which I mean possibly infinite, possibly finite lists) were a monad in a way which corresponds to zapp: there is a plausible candidate for the join (alluded to in other answers) but Jeremy Gibbons was kind enough to point out to us that it does not satisfy the monad laws. The counterexamples involve "ragged" lists of lists with varying finite lengths. Correspondingly, in the JFP article, we stood corrected. (We were rather happy about it, because we love to find applicative functors whose (<*>) is not the ap of a Monad.)

The necessarily infinite lists (i.e. *streams*), by ruling out the ragged cases, do indeed form a monad whose ap behaves like zapp. For a clue, note that Stream x is isomorphic to Nat -> x.

My apologies for the confusion. It's sometimes dangerous leaving old, unfinished drafts (replete with errors) lying (ha ha) around on the web.

Comment: Thanks! I do enjoy the older version having exercises, however :)

Comment: Oho! That makes rather more sense now. It seemed very strange to me that the exercise gave no indication that the suggested monad was only valid on lists of equal length.

Comment: @camccann That reminds me: all the fixed-length vector type-constructors are monadic, by a similar construction (including my favourite, the vectors of length zero).

Comment: @Conor McBride: Well, anything of fixed shape can be combined element-wise, all of which are the same rough family of monads that often make more sense as `Applicative`. You could "zip" trees instead of substituting at leaves, for instance. Interpreting `a -> b` as a structure of `b`s whose shape is given by `a`, the reader monad is one of these as well. There's bound to be some sort of tidy abstraction that generalizes the whole lot...

Answer (score 4):

The minimal complete definition of a Monad is either `fmap`+`return`+`join` or `return`+`(>>=)`. You can implement the one with the other:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a->m b) -> m b
(>>=) ma amb = join $ fmap amb ma

fmap :: Monad m => (a->b) -> m a -> m b
fmap f ma = ma >>= (return . f)
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
join mma = mma >>= id
```

Now, the implementation of `ap` can be rewritten in terms of `join` and `fmap`:

```
ap :: Monad m => m (a->b) -> m a -> m b
ap mf ma = do
    f <- mf
    a <- ma
    return (f a)
ap mf ma = do
    f <- mf
    fmap f ma
ap mf ma = join $ fmap (flip fmap ma) mf
```

---

In the exercise, the semantics of `fmap` and `return` and `ap` are given.
The rest will be obvious, as soon as you examine one example:

```
ap [f1,f2,f3...] [1,2,3...] = join $ fmap (flip fmap [1,2,3...]) [f1,f2,f3...]
                            = join $ [ [(f1 1), f1 2 , f1 3 ...]
                                     , [ f2 1 ,(f2 2), f2 3 ...]
                                     , [ f3 1 , f3 2 ,(f3 3)...]
                                     ...
                                     ]
                            = [(f1 1)
                              ,     (f2 2)
                              ,          (f3 3)
                              ...
                              ]
```

Comment: Just curious, does `flip fmap` make sense categorically? (If it's fair to interpret `fmap` as a functor of sorts?)

Comment: @gatoatigrado: It makes sense insofar as endofunctors on the category of Haskell types are equivalent to families of morphisms in the category. In categorical terms, `join :: m (m a) -> m a` is a natural transformation, and `fmap :: (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)` is a functor mapping between arrows in "different" categories... but Haskell flattens everything morphism-like into just `(->)`.